# Grid Filter Dropdown from Custom Post Type goes blank on Submit

Tags: custom-post-types

I am trying to filter a grid of players based on the clubs they are in. Players and Clubs are both custom page types

Now the Dropdown renders ok on first visit - rendering several teams ok - when the user clicks submit the correct params is added to the query string &dkFLAQueryTeam=5990 - however the Dropdown is now blank...

Any help appreciated

Actions

```
add_action('restrict_manage_posts', array(DKFLA_PREFIX . 'Players', DKFLA_PREFIX . 'Filters'));
add_filter('parse_query', array(DKFLA_PREFIX . 'Players', DKFLA_PREFIX . 'ParseQuery'));

public function dkFLAFilters()
{
    global $typenow, $wp_query, $post;

    $type = 'post';

    if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
        $type = $_GET['post_type'];
    }

    if (DKFLA_PLAYER_POST_TYPE == $type) {

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => DKFLA_TEAM_POST_TYPE,
        'numberposts' => -1,
        );

        $posts = get_posts($args);

        // print_r($args);
        // print_r($posts);
    ?>
        <select name="dkFLAQueryTeam">
        <option value="0"><?php _e('Filter By ', 'wose45436'); ?></option>
    <?php
        $current_v = isset($_GET['dkFLAQueryTeam']) ? $_GET['dkFLAQueryTeam']:'';

        foreach ($posts as $post) {

            printf
            (
            '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
            $post->ID,
            $post->ID == $current_v? ' selected="selected"':'',
            $post->post_title
            );
            }
    ?>
        </select>
    <?php
    }
}

/**
 * Submits the custom Filter Dropdown for Custom Posts
 */
public function dkFLAParseQuery($query)
{
    global $pagenow;

    $type = 'post';

    if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
        $type = $_GET['post_type'];
    }

    if (DKFLA_PLAYER_POST_TYPE == $type && is_admin() && $pagenow == 'edit.php' && !empty($_GET['dkFLAQueryTeam'])) {
        $query->query_vars['meta_key']   = 'dkFLAQueryTeam';
        $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $_GET['dkFLAQueryTeam'];
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Ian Warner ... Did you find the solution for this ?